# SELECT query using LIKE property in Microsoft Access returns no results when it should

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm sure I'm making some kind of rookie error here, but I have no idea what the problem is.  I am trying to run a simple query on one table in a microsoft access database using the LIKE property to find records that have a certain text string in a particular field.  More specifically, the table, called `Catreqs`, has a few fields, `bib_num`, `MARC_336`, `MARC_337`, and `MARC_338`.  The MARC_336 field has a text string in it and I want a query that selects all the records for which that text string includes the characters "txt".

Here's my query:

```
SELECT [Catreqs].record_num, [Catreqs].MARC_336
FROM [Catreqs]
WHERE [Catreqs].MARC_336 Like '%txt%';
```

I should note that I created this query in MS Access design view and this is the query that was generated when I switched to SQL view.  I am a little familiar with SQL and even less familiar with Access so this is actually my preferred way of dealing with it.

I've also tried using `Like '*txt*'` but that didn't return any results either.  For reference, here is the entire text string these characters are in:

```
text txt rdacontent
```

Any suggestions thoughts on why this fails and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your query really have three left parentheses and two right parentheses in the WHERE clause?  I'm surprised that runs at all.  Get rid of all of the parentheses.  You don't need them.

Comment: That's the sql generated by Access.  I've tried removing the parens a couple of times but Access puts them back in.

Comment: What data type is the MARC_336 column (open the table in design view to check)? The answer provided by TheDeveloper is correct. If you change % to * your query works. Right click on your query tab and go to the SQL View. Paste this in exactly as is: SELECT [Catreqs].record_num, [Catreqs].MARC_336 FROM Catreqs WHERE [Catreqs].MARC_336 Like '\*txt*';

Answer (score 3):

In Access, for a string you must use the `*` character.
Check if `[Catreqs]` has rows where `MARC_336` contains "txt".

This is the official documentation of Access:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Like-Operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931?ui=it-IT&rs=en-001&ad=IT&omkt=en-001

Comment: I tried using  * first to no avail.  There are definitely rows containing "txt" in the MARC_336 field.